# How to create dotted pair with nil

Tags: list, linked-list, lisp, common-lisp, cons

I have a list of queue names in the following form:

```
'("foo" "bar")
```

I am trying to store queues as assoc list in the following way:

```
'(("foo" . nil) ("bar" . nil))
```

Basically it is an assoc list with queues "foo" and "bar" which are currently empty. When Bob and Alice will be in the "foo" queue it should look like the following.

```
'(("foo" . ("alice" "bob")) ("bar" . nil))
```

How can I create this structure? I tried to achieve that by writing:

```
(mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cons x ''nil)) '("foo" "bar"))
```

which returned

```
'(("foo" QUOTE NIL) ("bar" QUOTE NIL))
```

this is probably not what I wanted because when I tried to push Bob to the "foo" queue it doesn't work as I wanted.

```
* (setf *tmp* '(("foo" . 'nil) ("bar" . 'nil)))
(("foo" QUOTE NIL) ("bar" QUOTE NIL))
* (push "bob" (caddr (assoc "foo" *tmp* :test #'string=)))
* *tmp*
(("foo" QUOTE ("bob")) ("bar" QUOTE NIL))
```

How can I create dotted pair with empty list after the dot?

**EDIT:**
Actually when I store such assoc list as the class slot it looks fine.

```
* (describe myClassInstance)
;; ...
QUEUES    = (("foo" . 'NIL) ("bar" . 'NIL))
;; ...
```

However after writing adding Bob to the "foo" queue all queues are being changed.

```
* (push "bob" (caddr (assoc "foo" (slot-value myClassInstance 'testClass::queues) :test #'string=))))
* (describe myClassInstance)
;; ...
QUEUES    = (("foo" . '("bob") ("bar" . '("bob"))
;; ...
```

What just happened here? It looks like the `cdr` part of all the queues was a single symbol and when I changed it's value in one place ("foo" queue) then it was changed in all the places (all the queues). Does it make any sense?

Comment: What is `(cons x ''nil)`??? Why is nil quoted twice?

Comment: what is `'(foo . 'nil)` supposed to be? Why is nil quoted?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I cannot find the source now but there was a place where I found this way to get dotted pair with the nil at the end. This is probably the issue but I cannot figure out how to create dotted pair with the empty list after the dot.

Comment: Think about it. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cons where the cdr is nil is exactly the same as a one-element list.  This is how lists are defined.

In other words, `(cons x nil)` is the same as `(list x)`.  You can imagine the result like this:

```
+-------+
| x |nil|
+-------+
```

A dotted pair where the cdr is a list is thus also just a list.

In other words, `'(("foo" . nil) ("bar" . nil))` is exactly the same as `'(("foo") ("bar"))`, even if the former notation perhaps better conveys your intent of treating it as an alist.

In the same way, `'(("foo" . ("alice" "bob")) ("bar" . nil))` is exactly the same as `'(("foo" "alice" "bob") ("bar"))`.

This means that you can create your data structure exactly as you want, but you can use e. g. `list` instead of `(lambda (x) (cons x nil))` (which is the same for a single argument).

```
(defun make-queues (&rest names)
  (mapcar #'list names))
```

You can also just push to the element found by `assoc` under a name:

```
(defun add-to-queue (queues queue-name item)
  (push item (cdr (assoc queue-name queues :test #'equal))))

(defun get-queue (queues queue-name)
  (cdr (assoc queue-name queues :test #'equal)))
```

The problem that you had last was that you put a literal into a list and tried to modify it: you put the same *literal list* containing only `nil` into each element of your alist.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much for clarifying this to me in such a clear way. So basically every list is an alist? Because even one-element list contains 'hidden' `nil` after the dot?

Comment: No, an alist is a list of conses.  A list is either a cons or nil (the empty list).  So any list of non-empty lists is also an alist.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are probably confusing the structure with its printed representation. `(cons x nil)` is the same as `'(x . nil)` and the same as `'(x)`. They will all print as `(x)`.

If you want to print as `'(x . nil)` you can write a print function for it, but the representations is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

**Compare with dots**

```
CL-USER 48 > (sdraw '(("foo" . ("alice" "bob")) ("bar" . nil)))

[*|*]---------------------------->[*|*]--->NIL
 |                                 |
 v                                 v
[*|*]--->[*|*]---->[*|*]--->NIL   [*|*]--->NIL
 |        |         |              |
 v        v         v              v
"foo"    "alice"   "bob"          "bar"
```

**and without dots**

```
CL-USER 49 > (sdraw '(("foo" "alice" "bob") ("bar")))

[*|*]---------------------------->[*|*]--->NIL
 |                                 |
 v                                 v
[*|*]--->[*|*]---->[*|*]--->NIL   [*|*]--->NIL
 |        |         |              |
 v        v         v              v
"foo"    "alice"   "bob"          "bar"
```

So, both notations are describing the same cons structure.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow most of the time I forget about awesome `sdraw`.